# print document to physical printer

Tags: r

I don't know if I'm overlooking it or not finding it, but is there a way to print
a text, word, or pdf document to a physical printer?

In python, it is done this way:

```
os.startfile("myPDF.pdf","print")
```

Is there anything similar in R or do I need to keep using `lpr.exe` in `system2()`?

Comment: Probably anything you'd find would be a light wrapper of `system2` much as you've been using.

Comment: @GregorThomas kind of figured that `system2()` would be the way